# APK failed to install on AVD despite installing on actual device

Tags: android, android-studio, kivy, android-virtual-device

I created a Kivy app and created a debug APK using Buildozer in a Linux virtual environment (my host laptop is Windows). When pushing this to my phone, the app works perfectly fine and 100% as expected. Before trying to push this to the Play Store, I wanted to test it on different devices using an emulator.

I installed Android Studio on my host laptop (as I am more comfortable there than Linux) and copied my .apk over. When I try and drag and drop my .apk into my Android virtual device, I get an error that says:

```
APK failed to install
Error: Could not parse error string
```

I even tried installing it directly into my emulator, by navigating to the platform-tools folder in the Sdk file, and copy and pasting my .apk there, and then trying to install it directly from cmd using:

```
adb install myapp-0.1-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk
```

however then I get an error message saying

```
adb: error: failed to get feature set: no devices/emulators found
```

When I check this in Android Studio by going to Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools tab, it clearly says that SDK manager and Emulator are both installed.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I sort this?

Thank you

Comment: Have you actually started the emulator? It sounds like it's telling you that none is available, not that none is in principle installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this was that the Android architecture needed to be x86 in order to run on the emulator.

To correct it, I had to change:

```
android.arch = armeabi-v7a
```

to

```
android.arch = x86
```

and then create the debug APK.

It might be necessary to change the p4a branch to `develop` and run a `buildozer android clean` to clean the build.